# Table saw blade width

Tags: woodworking

I need to make a straight slot cut with my 10" table saw, the cut needs to be 3/16" wide. what saw blade width would come close to this size.

Answer (score 5):

Use a standard 1/8" blade, but make two passes that overlap by 1/16".

Comment: @Tester101, move the fence (if ripping a groove) or workpiece (if crosscutting a dado) only 1/16" for the second pass.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to cut slots frequently, buy a dado blade.
[image]